# In Dart can hashCode() method calls return different values on equal (==) Objects?

Tags: dart, hashcode, checksum

My immediate project is to develop a system of CheckSums for proving that two somewhat complex objects are (functionally)EQUAL - in the sense that they have the same values for the critical properties.  (Have discovered that dates/times cannot be included, so can't use JSON on the bigger object - duh  :) (For my purposes) ).

To do this calling the `hashCode()` method on selected strings  seemed to be the way to go.

Upon implementing this, I note that in practice I am getting very different values on multiple runs of highest level objects that are functionally 'identical'.

There are a number of "nums" that I have not rounded, there are integers, bools, Strings and not much more.

I have 'always' thought that a hashCode on the same set of values would return the same number, am I missing something?

BTW the only context that I have found material on `hashCode()` has been with WebSockets.

Of course I can write my own String to a unique value but I want to understand if this is a problem with Dart or something else.

Answer (score 5):

I can attempt to answer the question posed in the title: "Can hashCode() method calls return different values on equal (==) Objects?"

Short answer: hash codes for two objects must be the same if those two objects are equals (==).

If you override `hashCode` you must also override `equals`. Two objects that are equal, as defined by `==`, must also have the same hash code.

However, hash codes do not have to be unique. That is, a perfectly valid hash code is the value `1`. A *good* hash code, however, should be uniformly distributed.

From the docs from [Object](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Object.html):

> Hash codes are guaranteed to be the same for objects that are equal
>   when compared using the equality operator ==. Other than that there
>   are no guarantees about the hash codes. They will not be consistent
>   between runs and there are no distribution guarantees.
>
> If a subclass overrides hashCode it should override the equality
>   operator as well to maintain consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I found the immediate problem.  The  object stringify() method, at one level,  was not getting called, but rather some stringify property that must exist in all objects (?).

With this fixed everything is working as exactly as I would expect, and multiple runs of our Statistical Studies are returning exactly the same CheckSum at the highest levels (based on some 5 levels of hierarchy).

Meanwhile the JSON.stringify has continued to fail.  Even in the most basic object.  I have not been able to determine what is causing to fail. Of course, the question is not how "stringify" is accomplished.

So, empirically at least, I believe it is true that "objects with equal properties" will return equal checkSums in Dart.  It was decided to round nums, I don't know if this was causing a problem - perhaps good to be aware of?   And, of course, remember to be beware of things like dates, times, or anything that could legitimately vary.

_swarmii

Comment: Hi, you can post some code that demonstrates the failure and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The doc linked by [Seth Ladd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123471/seth-ladd) now include info:

> They need not be consistent between executions of the same program and there are no distribution guarantees.`

so technically `hashCode` value can be change with same object in different executions for your question:

> I have 'always' thought that a hashCode on the same set of values would return the same number, am I missing something?